# Unable to delete the Restore Point Collection resource in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azureportal, azure-backup-vault, azure-disk

I have create the Linux VM with Ubuntu 20.04 OS and took the backup of that VM using Recovery Service Vault.

Then I removed all the resources as part of testing activity but only one resource is not deleting as you can see below screenshot:

[image]

**Error**:

```
Failed to delete restore point collection 'AzureBackup_newlinuxvm001_949978843408613'
```

**Update**:

Recovery Service Vault > Backup Items > Azure Virtual Machine:

[image]

> Make sure to delete any associated backup policies as well.

Deleted all the policies in RSV.

[image]

Comment: The error message suggests that there is a restore point collection associated with your Recovery Services Vault that you are trying to delete, and that the collection cannot be deleted. If there are recovery points associated with the collection, the collection cannot be deleted until the recovery points are deleted.

Comment: @VenkatV, I have added the restore point screenshot associated with the recovery service vault but I cannot see delete option for it.

Comment: Make sure to delete any associated backup policies as well.

Comment: Are you still facing same issue?

Comment: Backup Polices deleted, Disabled Soft delete, Security Features. Now deleting the backup item in Recovery Service Vault. and will be deleting the Recovery Service Vault. Once it is deleted, I'll update you (https://i.imgur.com/msnom0H.png)- (In a couple of minutes).

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/BhxuRcL.png - Backup item is deleted. https://i.imgur.com/sEqX9NX.png - RSV is also deleted successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to delete the Restore Point Collection resource in Azure Portal

The error message suggests that there is a restore point collection associated with your `Recovery Services Vault` that you are trying to delete. If there are recovery points associated with the collection, it cannot be deleted until the dependencies are removed from `RSV`.

Before deleting the `Recovery Services Vault` , ensure that all associated backup policies for the **virtual machine** within the **Recovery Services Vault** have been deleted.

[image]

If the problem persists, please go to settings and turn off the Soft deletion option.

[image]

After deleting all backup policies related to the `virtual machine`, the recovery service point was also deleted

[image]